# Quando usar Stateful ou Stateless

Tags: java, session, ejb

Gostaria de Saber qual a diferença e quando devo utilizar.

- Stateful
- StateLess

Answer (score 45, accepted):

A diferença entre **Stateful** e **Stateless** é que uma vai guardar o estado dos objetos(Stateful) e o outro vai reconhecer cada requisição como uma requisição nova(Stateless).

---

## **Stateless:**

- nenhum registro de todas as interações anteriores são salvos.
- cada interação é tratada com base nas informações disponíveis para a
  interação

Exemplo: Protocolos de Internet (IP), Protocolo de transmissão Hyper Text.

***Vantagens:***

- Redução o uso de memória no servidor.
- reduz problemas de sessão expirada

**Desvantagens:**

- Mais difícil de manter a interação do usuário e criar uma aplicação
  web sem emenda
- Pode exigir informações extras a serem enviados para e de cliente

---

## **Statefull**

- O Oposto do Stateless
- Mantém o controle do estado de interação
- Permite que os dados a ser mantido entre diferentes requisições.

Exemplo: Java:HttpSession, APS.net: Session

***Vantagens:***

- Manter o controle de um usuário durante toda a execução da aplicação.
- Mais intuitivo, dados de entidade podem ser mantidas no servidor entre requsições
- Pode melhorar o desempenho quando a recuperação de dados é necessária apenas uma vez.

***Desvantagens:***

- Requer memória a ser alocada para armazenar os dados
- Podem levar a uma diminuição do desempenho se o armazenamento de sessão não é mantido de forma eficiente

Comment: Esclarecedor, sanou minha dúvida quanto a este assunto

Answer (score 2):

Documentação da Oracle JAVA EE 6 a respeito:

**Stateful Session Beans**

The state of an object consists of the values of its instance variables. In a stateful session bean, the instance variables represent the state of a unique client/bean session. Because the client interacts (“talks”) with its bean, this state is often called the conversational state.

**Stateless Session Beans**

A stateless session bean does not maintain a conversational state with the client. When a client invokes the methods of a stateless bean, the bean’s instance variables may contain a state specific to that client but only for the duration of the invocation. When the method is finished, the client-specific state should not be retained.

Resumo bem simples:

Utilizar **Stateful** quando precisa manter o estado conversacional.

Exemplo: Em um carrinho de compras, onde você adiciona diversos itens e são itens pertinentes somente à um cliente, ou seja, existe a necessidade de manter a lista.

Utilizar **Stateless** quando não há necessidade de manter o estado dos valores.

Exemplo: Listar os produtos da loja (é a mesma lista para qualquer cliente, certo?)

O exemplo acima é bem simples, apenas para exemplificar a ideia de stateful e stateless, a utilização de EJBs geralmente é **muito** mais complexa.

Answer (score -1):

Pelo o que sei o Stateful mantém o estado do objeto durante a sessão. Já o StateLess mantém independente da sessão.

Exemplo você tem um programa de compra e venda de doláres. Nesse caso pode usar um serviço SStateLess para armazenar os dados da casa de cambio que contém a reserva. E um outro serviço Stateful para cada usuário (sessão) comprar ou vender doláres. O que importa aqui é a casa de cambio vai precisar compartilhar recursos entre vários usuários de forma simultânea, por isso precisa manter o estado dos recursos.

Aqui tem um detalhamento maior: http://www.devmedia.com.br/trabalhando-com-session-beans-stateless-e-stateful/28260

Comment: Então o StateLess é um `Singleton` ? não existe risco de ser criada uma nova instância?

Comment: Existe diferenças. Recomendo a leitura da documentação: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjg.html#gipim. Se tiver duvida post aqui que tento explicar melhor

Comment: certo, mas se existe diferenças acredito que seu exemplo não esteja completo...

Comment: O stateless não compartilha recursos, para cada chamada os objetos de instancia tem seu próprio estado até o fim da execução do metódo.

O singleton é compartilhado em todas as chamadas ao método, logo é objetos de instancia podem ser compartilhados entre as chamadas.

Comment: Que mistureba galera.
Stateless trata cada requisição independentemente.
Statefull tem session pra identificar o usuário e restaurar o estado entre cada requisição.

Singleton é outro bixo em outra camada.