# O que é PJAX e como detectar uma chamada PJAX no back-end?

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, pjax

Andei lendo algumas coisas sobre o *PJAX*, mas está um pouco confuso o seu funcionamento independente de frameworks, vi artigos mas todos voltados ao YUI ou plugins para jQuery, realmente não ficou muito claro a sua implementação.

Se entendi bem o *PJAX* é a interação do DOM (através de javascript) com o back-end através do `XmlHttpRequest`.

O que eu gostaria de entender:

- Ele deve ser usado com `pushState` ou isto é apenas um tipo de implementação?
- Ele é usado para carregar conteúdo HTML (os plugins que testei carregavam os dados em um elemento apontado)?
- Sei que devo ter que enviar header através do `setrequestheader`, mas eu vi dois headers diferentes serem usados, então como "detectar" uma chamada PJAX? (eu sei que no real não tem como diferenciar uma requisição `XmlHttpRequest` de outros tipos de requisição)

Answer (score 3):

PJAX é um acrônimo para o PushState Ajax, e nada mais é que a combinação de métodos e tecnologias já existentes:

1. O método [PushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method) pertence a [API History](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) do HTML5 e com ele pode-se gerenciar a URL e a pilha de histórico de um site. ¹
2. AJAX significa Asynchronous JavaScript e XML. Em poucas palavras, é o uso do objeto XMLHttpRequest para se comunicar com os scripts do lado do servidor. ²

> Ele deve ser usado com pushState ou isto é apenas um tipo de implementação?

Sim, deve ser usado com PushState. Creio eu que nessa pergunta você confundiu-se com os protocolos HTTP [Stateless](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-state/) e Stateful. ³

> Ele é usado para carregar conteúdo HTML (os plugins que testei
>   carregavam os dados em um elemento apontado)?

Ele é usado para carregar conteúdo do servidor, de forma assíncrona, utilizando as características do método PushState para uma melhor experiência no front-end

> Sei que devo ter que enviar header através do setrequestheader, mas eu
>   vi dois headers diferentes serem usados, então como "detectar" uma
>   chamada PJAX? (eu sei que no real não tem como diferenciar uma
>   requisição XmlHttpRequest de outros tipos de requisição)

Nos métodos implementados na maioria dos frameworks, é possível detectar uma chamada PJAX através do HEADER `X-PJAX`

[¹ Fonte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh920758(v=vs.85).aspx)

[² Fonte](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)

[³ Fonte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86848/quando-usar-stateful-ou-stateless)