# @Stateless em projeto CDI

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, jsf, java-ee, cdi, ejb

Pessoa, tenho a seguinte estrutura no meu projeto (CDI):

BEAN:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class ClienteMB extends BaseAbstractMB<Cliente, ClienteDTO> implements Serializable {

    @Inject
    private ClienteService clienteService;

    // METODOS
}
```

Service (interface):

```
public interface ClienteService extends BaseService<Cliente, ClienteDTO>{
// METODOS
}
```

ServiceImpl:

```
@Transactional(rollbackOn = Exception.class)
public class ClienteServiceImpl extends BaseAbstractServiceImpl<Cliente, ClienteDTO> implements ClienteService {
// METODOS
}
```

Até ai, essa estrutura está correta, certo? Porém em outro projeto ao qual trabalho na classe ClienteServiceImpl temos uma anotação chamada `@Stateless` (Conceito: Nenhum registro de todas as interações anteriores são salvos)

Minha dúvida é, preciso realmente ter a anotação `@Stateless`? Se sim, qual sua real utilidade? Pois uma vez o projeto sendo CDI, a anotação `@Stateless` é EJB, não? 
E por que em um projeto eu não uso a anotação e outro uso, e ambos funcional normalmente.

Segundo um colega meu, se eu não tiver a anotação `@Stateless` não daria para fazer um `@Inject`, mas no projeto que eu não uso a `@Stateless` eu consigo fazer um `@Inject` normalmente.

Alguém sabe explicar bem direitinho isso?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Quando usar Stateful ou Stateless](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86848/quando-usar-stateful-ou-stateless)

Comment: E se não usar nenhum dos dois, no que impacta? Neste caso, consigo fazer inject sem nenhum problema não usando o stateless?